# Plotly: How to save only main figure to png?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

This code:

```
fig = go.Figure(data =
go.Contour(
    z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
))

fig.write_image("logs/test.png")
```

Produces this:

[image]

I would like only the main contour plot saved, with no x and y labels and no colorbar.

I expect that I could take a reliable sub-area of the image, but maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                  xaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False})
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as   go

fig = go.Figure(data =
go.Contour(
    z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
))

fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                  xaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False})
fig.show()

fig.write_image("contour2.png")
```